# List of bad things that happened throughout 3 weeks

Tags: tisha-bav, three-weeks

Anyone have an online list of all the bad things throughout history that have happened to us throughout the 3 weeks? Mainly looking for things on Tisha B’av but also the rest of the 3 weeks or 9 days too

Answer (score 2):

For Tisha B'Av, go to Mishna in Ta'anit 4:6:

משנה תענית ד׳:ו׳
חֲמִשָּׁה דְבָרִים אֵרְעוּ אֶת אֲבוֹתֵינוּ בְּשִׁבְעָה עָשָׂר בְּתַמּוּז וַחֲמִשָּׁה בְּתִשְׁעָה בְאָב... בְּתִשְׁעָה בְאָב נִגְזַר עַל אֲבוֹתֵינוּ שֶׁלֹּא יִכָּנְסוּ לָאָרֶץ, וְחָרַב הַבַּיִת בָּרִאשׁוֹנָה וּבַשְּׁנִיָּה, וְנִלְכְּדָה בֵיתָר, וְנֶחְרְשָׁה הָעִיר. מִשֶּׁנִּכְנַס אָב, מְמַעֲטִין בְּשִׂמְחָה:

But as for a longer list:

1. The spies returned with a bad report.
2. Both Holy Temples were destroyed.
3. The battle at Betar was lost.
4. The romans plowed the Beit HaMikdash.
5. The First Crusade officially began.
6. The Jews were expelled from England.
7. The Jews were banished from Spain.
8. Both World Wars began.
9. Treblinka death camp begins operating, and start of deportations from the Warsaw Ghetto.

Comment: You can edit to include the full mishnah (OP is also asking about the larger 3 week period starting with 17 Tamuz as well). And here are couple of other occasions you can add to your list: King Philip expelled France's Jews on the 10th of Abh. The "Final Solution" was decreed on the 8th of Abh. The expulsion of the Jews of 'Azza by the Israeli government was on the 10th of Abh.